# How make numbering fields with same name?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have multiple fields with same name in a single form.

```
Name 1<input name="Name[]" value="Loren" />
Name 2<input name="Name[]" value="tom"  />
Name 3<input name="Name[]" value="dolor" />
```

This way php will receive an array of addresses.- Name Loren,tom,dolor. 
How can i make numbering fields when i get it? - Name 1 Loren, 2 tom, 3 dolor.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please update the question to explain a bit more what you mean. Do you have any attempt that we can look at? You've also tagged jQuery. How is that related to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can put almost anything you like into the `name` attribute. By default name arrays commence numbering at 0 so if you are submitting your form by post and you `echo $_POST['Name']` you will see

```
Array (
    [0] => Loren
    [1] => tom
    [2] => dolor
)
```

However you can explicitly number the inputs if you like e.g.

```
Name 1<input name="Name[1]" value="Loren" />
Name 2<input name="Name[2]" value="tom"  />
Name 3<input name="Name[3]" value="dolor" />
```

and then `echo $_POST['Name']` will output:

```
Array (
    [1] => Loren
    [2] => tom
    [3] => dolor
)
```

Or you can even name them e.g.

```
Name 1<input name="Name[Name 1]" value="Loren" />
Name 2<input name="Name[Name 2]" value="tom"  />
Name 3<input name="Name[Name 3]" value="dolor" />
```

and `echo $_POST['Name']` will output:

```
Array (
    [Name 1] => Loren
    [Name 2] => tom
    [Name 3] => dolor
)
```